# Android create local folder and backup database file there

Tags: android, backup

I want to achieve a simple thing - after pressing a button, I want to copy the application database file (from database folder) to a newly created folder BKP (create if not exists).

The problem is, I always get

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/my_package/bkp/mydb.db (No such file or directory)
```

I tried it like this:

```
  public void backUp() {
    try {

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            String currentDBPath ="/data/my_package/databases/mydb.db";
            String backupDBPath = "/data/my_package/bkp/mydb.db";
            String dir = "/data/my_package/bkp/";

        File directory = new File(dir);

        if (! directory.exists()){
           directory.mkdir(); }

            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is successful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It seems the bkp directory is not even created.

However not sure if this is a good approach, I only want to backup one database file, because if the user will have a new device or uninstalls and reinstalls the app, the db will be empty.

Maybe a good solution would be to download the db file to general Download folder, so the user could copy it anywhere and restore.

I want to have some backup (not cloud solutions) and no external drive, as nowadays the disk spaces are large for androids and only a few people still uses SD cards.

Comment: Have a look at currentDB.getAbsolutePath() and backupDB.getAbsolutePath() to see that you build up your File instances wrong. Not possible full paths.

Comment: getAbsolutePath gives me: /data/data/mypackage/databases/mydb.db. If I change currentDBpath to: /my_package/databases/mydb.db then it even can't find my database: /data/my_package/databases/mydb.db (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the DIR path. As other paths have Environment.getDataDirectory() + their path, the directory path was without getDataDirectory, so it had only one data in path. Now with data/data it worked and the directory is created!

```
 String dir = "/data/data/my_package/bkp/";
```